# Python: googlefinance json.dumps error

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to download stock price data from googlefinance to excel using Python 3.6. I use the following code to get the data into Python. I have this information now in data but would like to save it in variables/array. However if I try print (data['ID']) I get "string indices must be integers"?

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import json
print( json.dumps(getQuotes('AAPL'), indent=2))
[
  {
    "Index": "NASDAQ", 
    "LastTradeWithCurrency": "129.09", 
    "LastTradeDateTime": "2015-03-02T16:04:29Z", 
    "LastTradePrice": "129.09", 
    "Yield": "1.46", 
    "LastTradeTime": "4:04PM EST", 
    "LastTradeDateTimeLong": "Mar 2, 4:04PM EST", 
    "Dividend": "0.47", 
    "StockSymbol": "AAPL", 
    "ID": "22144"
  }
]
data = json.dumps(getQuotes('AAPL'), indent=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of a dict, but you don't need `json.dumps`, the return type is already a list. If you want to access the dictionary, you need to extract it from the list:

```
array_data = getQuotes('AAPL')
data = array_data[0]
print(data['ID'])
```

Comment: Many thanks! Unfortunately I still get the error message : TypeError: string indices must be integers after print(data['ID'])

Comment: Hi, i tested on local. The problem was the json.dumps. You dont need to do that. I edited the answers. hope this helps